# How an angular object gets the value of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

How can I make the object inherit all the properties from the other object.

This is the code:

```
this.makeReady = function(order) {
    var tempOrder = angular.copy(order);
    tempOrder.status = 1;
    angular.forEach(tempOrder.items, function(item){
        item.status = 1;
    })
    return $http.put('/rest/change/invoice/'+order.id+'/', tempOrder).success(function(){
        order = tempOrder; // this doesn't work
    });
}
```

In case of success: change the value of that object.

Comment: What are you passing into the order parameter of your makeReady function? If it's $scope.order, then just use `$scope.order = tempOrder;` in your success function.

Comment: `$scope.allOrders` contains all orders, so when i change `order` it will affect on allOrders..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to directly edit the order in your `$scope.allOrders` and see if that gets you the behavior that you are looking for.

```
    this.makeReady = function (order) {
        var tempOrder = angular.copy(order);
        var orderIndex = $scope.allOrders.indexOf(order);
        tempOrder.status = 1;

        angular.forEach(tempOrder.items, function(item) {
            item.status = 1;
        });

        return $http.put('/rest/change/invoice/' + order.id + '/', tempOrder).success(function () {
            $scope.allOrders[orderIndex] = tempOrder;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
this.makeReady = function(order) {
    var tempOrder = angular.copy(order);
    tempOrder.status = 1;
    angular.forEach(tempOrder.items, function(item){
        item.status = 1;
    })
    $http.put('/rest/change/invoice/'+order.id+'/', tempOrder).success(function(){
        order = tempOrder; // this doesn't work
        return order;
    });
}
```

or use callBack function

```
  this.makeReady = function(order, callback) {
        var tempOrder = angular.copy(order);
        tempOrder.status = 1;
        angular.forEach(tempOrder.items, function(item){
            item.status = 1;
        })
        $http.put('/rest/change/invoice/'+order.id+'/', tempOrder).success(function(){
            order = tempOrder; // this doesn't work
            callback(order)
        });
    };
```

call function

```
this.makeReady({status:1, data:2, items:{status:1}}, function(data){
// this data your order variable in service
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your first example would work as expected. $http.put is not synchronous. The callback example should work.

Comment: First example doesn't work.. second example does not fit in my logic, becouse when i update this order, it will be updated on allOrders variable.. first example would be great if works..